# MySQL INSERT with CALL

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that splits a string and ends with a select.

I would like to run an insert on the stored procedure like you would do an insert on a select

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO ....
CALL sp_split...
```

My split looks like this:

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `split_with_id`(id INT, input varchar(1000), delim VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    declare foundPos tinyint unsigned; 
    declare tmpTxt varchar(1000); 
    declare delimLen tinyint unsigned; 
    declare element varchar(1000); 

drop temporary table if exists tmpValues; 
create temporary table tmpValues 
( 
    `id` int not null default 0,
    `values` varchar(1000) not null default '' 
) engine = memory; 

set delimLen = length(delim); 
set tmpTxt = input; 

set foundPos = instr(tmpTxt,delim); 

while foundPos <> 0 do 
    set element = substring(tmpTxt, 1, foundPos-1); 
    set tmpTxt = replace(tmpTxt, concat(element,delim), ''); 


    insert into tmpValues (`id`, `values`) values (id, element); 

    set foundPos = instr(tmpTxt,delim); 
end while; 

if tmpTxt <> '' then 
    insert into tmpValues (`id`, `values`) values (id, tmpTxt); 
end if; 

select * from tmpValues;
```

END

Comment: I believe this question may be what you are trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Comment: That is a grate article for MS SQL but unfutunately MySQL does not support exec

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper function and have it call the procedure. Then `SELECT` it normally.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `f_wrapper_split` (strin VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE r VARCHAR(255);
    CALL sp_split(strin);
    RETURN r;
END
$$
```

Of course, if `sp_split` returns multiple results, you'll need to adapt the function to, perhaps, take an `INT` input as well and return you that particular result. Then just call it multiple times.

It's not very pretty, but that's the best I can think of offhand.

Comment: Would it be possible to include the DDL for `sp_split` into the question?

Comment: My split returns a table: AccountID | PermissionID I need to find a way to do the folloing code "INSERT INTO tablename (AccountID, PermissionID ) SELECT AccountID, PermissionID FROM tempTble" but with a "CALL" Something like "INSERT INTO tablename (AccountID, PermissionID ) CALL sp_split()"

Comment: Are you doing a `SELECT` inside a procedure and letting it bleed the resultset to the outer scope? Because that's not the same as returning a `TABLE` type in SQL Server or the like.

Comment: I am not returning a table I am calling select at the end do you have a better salution I added my split in the question above

Comment: Why don't you just insert into the `tmpValues` table? Why bother with the `SELECT` at all?